# How to make perfect/smooth selection

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, pen-tool, mockup

As I was trying to change the colour of the t-shirt for my mockup, I ran into this problem. I know that first you have to cut and put the shirt into a seperate layer and the model will have an empty area in the middle. This is my result [image]

So I'm pretty much satisfied with how the shirt looks like but what I don't like is, if you take a closer look, it has a white, jagged line around that totally doesn't look natural at all (btw I used the pen tool for this). What do you guys think may be the problem here? Is it because of my terrible selection skill or something else? Hope you all could deliver a solution, that would be highly appreciated

Here is the original image if anyone would like to demonstrate[image]

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to GDSE!  when I have to make alterations like that, I usually like to apply a 3-5px feather to the edge of my mask to soften the edge.  The other thing, is when you make your selection, don't forget to also select the white edge in the shadow areas.  that needs to stay in, but it will need to be colorized.  If I get a chance, I'll try to post a tutorial for you if one of our other talented members doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: ermm.. what software?

Comment: @Alith7 I did try to do that a couple of times but it eventually leaves me with a png line instead of white which makes it even more unrealistic. Since I was trying to make a t-shirt mockup, it means (probably) I have to cut out the shirt and leave an empty png space in the middle of the model. But if you had a chance to make a tutorial on this, please do and that would be a lifesaver.

Comment: @scott it's Adobe Photoshop 2020. Sorry for the late heads up because I thought photoshop was the norm around here. I just joined this forum like yesterday.

Comment: .. truth of the matter is.. all it takes is *practice*. Like any skill, the more you do it, the better you are at it.

Answer (score 1):

As Vincent has already said in his answer, the line is already present in the image. It looks as though it has already been badly edited. However, if you must edit this actual photograph and don't have access to a better unedited photo, then you can make it look a little better. It's not easy, and will take some manual retouching work.

I used the Select and Mask functionality in Photoshop CC

1. I made a selection of the T-shirt with the Quick Select tool as accurately as possible, this involved zooming in and using a small brush. Then I went into Select and Mask, and used the Smoothing and Shift Edge sliders to make the selection smoother, and slightly overlap the problematic white line as best I could.
2. I set the output to "New layer with layer mask", and added a Color Overlay effect, with the blend mode set to Multiply.
3. Finally I edited the layer mask manually by painting on it with a small soft edged brush to fix the areas that didn't quite work during the selection process. The idea here being to have the mask overlap the white line so that it gets colourized by the Colour Overlay, but not too much or you'll end up with a dark line.

The result is not perfect by any means, but the line is much less noticeable.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the incredibly useful trick. I actually used a different technique which involves cutting out the the shirt from the model and leave an empty png. Then for the shirt itself, I extracted the shadow using alpha channel and put it in another layer on top of shirt so that when changing the colour of the shirt, the shadow will not be affected. Extremely sorry for not being specific on the post but this is a project for my school web programming assignment where I allow users to apply new colours onto the shirt using html. Would your technique still apply tho? Thanks again

Comment: I'm sorry but I thought this was just a regular photo edit. Unfortunately questions about html are off-topic here, and I can't promise this technique will be any use for your particular requirements.

Comment: No. No you get the wrong idea, this topic isn't meant for html i was just explaining the technique I used and was wondering if yours could still be of help. The html bit was indeed extra but it was never the main point. Hope that clarifies

Comment: Sure, the masking techniques I used to get a smooth result are valid for any masking job, no matter how the layers are constructed.

Answer (score 0):

The jagged line is already in the original image, that shirt has alreay been re/discoloured at least once. My advice would be to find a better source image without the line, preferably one with a distinct colour shirt and then use `Select > Colour Range...` (in Photoshop, that is) to make a good selection in a few clicks.